# MSP getting powered up from GPIO

Tags: microcontroller, usb, gpio, msp

On a demo board I have, USB 5V rail is connected via a resistor divider to one of the GPIO's of MSP. MSP itself is powered from PCIE 3v3AUX rail.

[image: Here is the connection on the board]

In one of the cases when the board is not connected in the PCIE slot but it is connected to USB, I see that the GPIO pin is set as 3.3V. Also, when I measured the Vcc pin of MSP, I measure 0.7V.

I as assuming that the ESD clamp diode is turning on, but do not understand why there is 0.7V on Vcc pin of MSP. I am expecting that the drop across the diode will be 0.7V, so Vcc pin should be ~ 2.6V. Is my theory incorrect??

Can you help me understand what can cause 0.7V at MSP power pins?

Answer (score 3):

Some low voltage in the vicinity of what you are seeing is where the internal circuitry just starts to be active enough (but not yet functional) to draw meaningful current.  Likely this is related to threshold voltage of internal FETs, or junctions, or similar.  As a result, this voltage at which current draw starts to increase is where an *equilibrium* is reached with the tiny current sourced through the series resistor and GPIO protection diodes.

Although this voltage isn't sufficient to make the chip functional, there are a number of parts (especially more advanced SoCs that may not have brownout detectors, vs MCU's that often do) which can as a result of this get into a state from which they won't do a clean power on reset when "real" power is applied.

This situation tends to be outside of data sheet allowances; preferably you would design to avoid it happening.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Chris. Can you explain in a little more detail how it might effect other devices with power on reset when "real" power is applied.